# Run Python script to retrieve file links from Amazon S3

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I have mp3 files stored in Amazon S3 and I have a MySQL database with a table called Songs. I want to run a Python script that updates my database by going to Amazon S3, retrieves details of the mp3 files (using ID3 for example) and then fills the Songs table in my database. I'm using Django. Is there any way that allows me to run this script by a simple click on an "update library" button for example through the Django admin panel? Also, is it possible to run it on a schedule?

P.S I'm new to both Django and Amazon S3

**EDIT**:
I wrote a small script that grabs meta tags from mp3 files in my local machine. Here is the code for it :

```
import eyeD3
import sys
import urllib
import os

class Track():
    def __init__(self, audioFile):
        self.title = audioFile.getTag().getTitle()
        self.artist = audioFile.getTag().getArtist()
        self.year = audioFile.getTag().getYear()
    self.genre = audioFile.getTag().getGenre()
    self.length = audioFile.getPlayTimeString()
    self.album = audioFile.getTag().getAlbum()

def main():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
        for f in files:
            if eyeD3.isMp3File(f):
                audioFile = eyeD3.Mp3AudioFile(root+'/'+f)
                t = Track(audioFile)
                print t.artist," ",t.title, " ", t.length, " ", t.album, " ", t.genre    




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I would like to find a way to run this script on Django even if ti's locally. I hope my point is clearer.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a look at [Boto](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) and also [django-storages](http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) for ideas on how to do what you'd like. django-storages makes it dead-simple to replace Django's FileStorage mechanism so you can upload imaes/files directly to your bucket(s) at S3.

Reading from S3 and updating your database objects is just the opposite workflow, but Boto makes it simple to get connected to the bucket(s) and read information.

Hope that helps you out.

Comment: In fact, i don't need to store the data on Django (from what i understood in your post) but i need to retrieve data from Amazon S3 (or local machine at first) and then upload these data on MySQL databse running with Django. Please read my edited post ! thanks

Comment: Sure, I don't see why you couldn't do something similar using Boto to read the objects in your S3 bucket and then do whatever you'd like with them.

Comment: I didn't try it yet actually. I'm trying to run the script locally, fetch tags from music in my local machine first, my first problem is that I don't know how to run it locally first, as a separate script or something, knwo what I mean?

Comment: Run it locally, as in within a Django application? If you need the context of a Django application, you can set up the Django environment as part of your script, or you could create a management command and run it with manage.py or, you could even run the code within a view; there are several options.

Comment: It depends on what's best suited for your app, there's no "right" way to do it, give the context of your question.

Comment: I have a playlist of songs (that are hosted on AS3) on the website and I need the admin to do be able to do an update of the database when he needs to, so I must make it straightforward for them without going to the console and type code there etc, so i guess creating a view is most suited, any suggestions?

Comment: In that case, yes, I would create a custom view for admin that performs the function(s) you need.

Comment: it's done actually ! the only problem is that I can't perform the test on all the files of a given folder. Like, I run (almost the same) script but it displays the info of the first mp3 file only

Comment: Hmm. Sounds like there might be an issue with how you're accessing the object in the loop.

Comment: I just can't print them on my screen but I could loop and insert data in the database. Maybe I should print it in my web page instead of looping in the view function and try print.